# Do players in the same clan, but on PS4 and Xbox One, contribute to clan XP in Destiny 2?

Tags: destiny-2

Do players in the same clan, but on PS4 and Xbox One, contribute to clan XP in Destiny 2? I would assume this is the case.

Is there any downside of having a cross-platform clan, other than players from different platforms not being able to play with each other?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like, yes, this is the case. From [this Q&A thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/DestinyTheGame/comments/6yxz4m/are_destiny_2_clans_cross_platform/):

> It is cross platform. I am the only ps4 player in my clan, while everyone else is on Xbox, yet I still see the XP gains from them.

---

> Do you get the rewards from them?

---

> Yep, all the engrams and everything.